# How to convert .raw audio input to .m4a with ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have this ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg -i testing.m4a -acodec pcm_s16le -f rawvideo tentative.raw
```

I'd like to know the command to convert tentative.raw back to testing.m4a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just found a way of doing it.

```
ffmpeg -f s16le -sample_rate 16000 -channels 2 -i tentative.raw -c:a aac testing.m4a
```

If your `ffmpeg` is outdated you may need to add `-strict experimental` to encode with the native FFmpeg AAC encoder (`-c:a aac`).